# Div clonada (jquery) elementos só funcionam na div Original

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando a "clonagem" de divs em jquery, e dentro delas tenho outras divs que ao clicar em um botão ex.: DIV 1, DIV 2, DIV 3 com javascript mostra o conteúdo de cada div. Só que ao adicionar a nova div(clonada) quando clicar no botão para mostrar a div ocultada dentro da clonada aparece a mudança somente na div original, e na clonada fica igual..

Ao utilizar o comando "CLONAR" do Jquery na div "engloba" só funciona o mostrar/ocultar na original e não na clonada.

SEGUE ABAIXO:

```js
<script>
function Listagem(tr) {
 
if (tr == 1) {
document.getElementById('div1').style.display="block";
document.getElementById('div2').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('div3').style.display="none";

}else if (tr == 2) {
document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('div2').style.display="block";
document.getElementById('div3').style.display="none";
}
else if (tr == 3) {
document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('div2').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('div3').style.display="block";
}
</script>

<!--  Clona DIVS em jquery--> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 
$("#mais").click(function() {
linha = $("#engloba").html();
$("#conteudo_engloba").append("<br />"+linha+"<br />");
});
 
});
</script>
```

```html
<!-- botao que "clona" a div (engloba)  -->
<form>
<input type="button" name="" value="+" id="mais">
</form>

<div id="conteudo_engloba">
<div id="engloba">

<a onClick="Listagem(1);" id="btDetalhes" >DIV1</a>
    <a onClick="Listagem(2);" id="btDetalhes" >DIV2</a>
    <a onClick="Listagem(3);" id="btDetalhes" >DIV3</a>

<div id="div1">DIV 1</div>
<div id="div2">DIV 2</div>
<div id="div3">DIV 3</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Da pra mostrar seu código? `html` e `js`

Comment: Coloque seu código (html, css e javascript) aqui, ou melhor ainda, no jsfiddle que será mais fácil lhe ajudar.

Comment: Alterei e adicionei o código para ficar melhor...

Comment: Certamente o problema é que você faz tudo pelo ID das divs, e quando você clona, acaba clonando isso também, o ideal é que você alterasse essa informação ao clonar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em HTML não podes ter mais do que um elemento com ID duplicada. O `.getElementById()` procura um elemento único, e quando tens vários elementos com a mesma ID a coisa deixa de funcionar como esperas.

Para além disso fica uma sugestão de simplificação de código. Assim podes adicionar N linhas e o `display = 'block'` ou `display = 'none'` não precisa de ser tão longo e demasiado adaptado.

Repara que fiz mudanças no HTML e no JavaScript

```js
function Listagem(index, el) {
    var divs = el.parentElement.querySelectorAll('div');
    for (var i = 0, l = divs.length; i < l; i++) {
        divs[i].style.display = i == index ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var linha = $(".engloba:first").clone();
    $("#mais").click(function() {
        $("#conteudo_engloba").append(linha.clone());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- botao que "clona" a div (engloba)  -->
<form>
    <input type="button" name="" value="+" id="mais">
</form>

<div id="conteudo_engloba">
    <div class="engloba">
        <a onClick="Listagem(0, this);">DIV1</a>
        <a onClick="Listagem(1, this);">DIV2</a>
        <a onClick="Listagem(2, this);">DIV3</a>

        <div>DIV 1</div>
        <div>DIV 2</div>
        <div>DIV 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pfmfoe30/

Comment: Sérgio, agora que consertei uma coisa estragou outra.. Dentro dessas divs tenho SELECT que abre outras divs(que troquei por span para funcionar com seu código)...Tipo select option  1 abre div1, option 2 abre div 2... A questão é, Como fazer um select com Onclick para abrir essas divs dentros das divs que foram clonadas

Comment: @Alh usa o meu jsFiddle e adapta. Coloca de volta aqui que eu dou uma olhada.

Comment: segue adaptação do html do jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pfmfoe30/11/

Comment: @Alh vi agora o teu jsFiddle. Acho que esse problema pertence a outra pergunta. O que perguntaste aqui _"Div clonada (jquery) elementos só funcionam na div Original"_ respondi em cima: IDs duplicados, etc... mas se quiseres colocar outra pergunta posso ajudar claro (ou outros utilizadores do site).

Comment: exatamente isso... Os elementos só estão funcionando na div original e não na clonada.. No caso funcionou para ocultar/mostrar a div principal, agora falta o SELECT e o CHECKBOX ocultar/mostrar a divs internas! Foi isso que adicionei ao HTML do jsfiddle, pois a tua resposta funcionou na div principal da clonada, agora falta a Div filho e "Neto" da principal funcionar De acordo com o selects e checkbox, seguindo o raciocionio da tua resposta da div principal.

Comment: os selects e checkbox são dentro da div que foi clonada por isso os elementos não funcionam pelo ID, eu acho que seria o mesmo raciocinio para complementar igual sua resposta da pergunta...